# Objective-C error EXC_BAD_ACCESS help please

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am currently using the pragmatic screencast on Objective-C to help me program in objective-c. I have a background in Java and C++, but I am having a very difficult time getting used to everything in Objective(Mostly because I am not comfortable with the syntax). 
Below is the error I am receiving with all the code.
I am also getting a warning in movie.m class as well: Wirtable atomic property 'title'
cannot be pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter

thanks for your help.

I am receive this error

```
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
warning: Couldn't find class validation function, calling methods on uninitialized objects may deadlock your program.
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

I ran it through the debugger and the address of movie in the code below is in red

main.m

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

Movie *movie = [[Movie alloc] initWithTitle:@"iron man"
                                andRating:5
                                    andYear:2008];

[movie play];
NSLog(@"our movie is %@", movie);

[pool drain];
return 0;}
```

Movie.h

```
    interface Movie : NSObject {
    NSString *title;
    int rating;
    int year;
}
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle
          andRating:(int)newRating
            andYear:(int) year;

@property(assign) NSString *title;
@property(assign) int rating;
@property(assign) int year;
-(void) play;

@end
```

Movie.m

```
    #import "Movie.h"


@implementation Movie

@synthesize title;
@synthesize rating;
@synthesize year;
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle
                    andRating:(int)newRating
           andYear:(int)newYear;
{

    self = [super init];
    if(nil != self){
        self.title = newTitle;
        self.rating = newRating;
        self.year = newYear;
    }
    return self;

}
-(NSString *) description{
    NSString *oldDescription = [super description];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ title =%@, rating =%d year=%@",
            oldDescription, self.title, self.rating, self.year];
}
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)newTitle {
    title = [newTitle capitalizedString];
}
-(void) play {
    NSLog(@"Playing %@", self);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `year=%@` when it should be `year=%d`.

Some more random thoughts:

You should retain or better even copy the title instead of assigning it.

The init method should be named

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle
                    rating:(int)aRating
                    year:(int)aYear;
```

Don't forget a `dealloc` method then.

Comment: Thank you that helped. It works now, I haven't gotten to the point to dealloc, but thank. I keep making that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `title` property is an object type and so should in generally be either `retain` or `copy` -- in the case of `NSString` properties, it is traditional to use `copy` to avoid issues when you're passed an `NSMutableString` instead.

```
@property (copy) NSString* title;
```

Since you explicitly define the setter, you then need to implement this policy yourself, something like this:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)newTitle
{
    [title release];
    title = [[newTitle capitalizedString] copy];
}
```

You'll also need to include a `dealloc` method to clean up:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into, I believe it will change; I have only gone through the first part, the second part address memory management.

Comment: @seanb11 You should click the little arrow outline by the side of Eiko's answer to acknowledge it as correct. And enjoy the next part -- hopefully the above will make more sense as you go on :)